# get key of element in @each directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I found an @each directive that seems to be useful but as I checked in the definition in:
`Illuminate\View\Factory;`
in:
`public function renderEach($view, $data, $iterator, $empty = 'raw|')` 
the `$iterator` stands for the item that is actually iterated.

Could I somehow obtain the key of the item in the `$view` partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you tried to use the $key variable?

If you take a look in the method renderEach you'll see this line:

```
$result .= $this->make(
         $view, ['key' => $key, $iterator => $value]
)->render();
```

Look in data array: ['key' => $key]

Just use $key inside the view.